# Htaccess 301 redirect on last directory matching the with a sub directory

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hello I have URLs like this

```
https://example.com/product-category/abc1/abc2/abc3
https://example.com/product-category/p1/p2/
https://example.com/product-category/pa1/pa2/pa3/pa4
```

If condition matches with url having sub directory product-category then it should redirect to last directory of URL.

Like

```
https://example.com/product-category/abc1/abc2/abc3 to https://example.com/abc3
https://example.com/product-category/p1/p2/ to https://example.com/p2/
https://example.com/product-category/pa1/pa2/pa3/pa4 to  https://example.com/pa4/
```

I have written code like this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product-category(.*)/([^/]+)/?$ https://example.com/$1
```

in htaccess file. But its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below, I am using complete mod_rewrite solution first checking uri initial part after that only getting the last portion of url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product-category
RewriteRule (.*)/([^/]+)/?$ https://example.com/$2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: How does it care about the `product-category` directory?

Comment: @VaibhavJain sorry I overlooked that please try with edited.

Comment: Yes, It's working with redirect. You just need to modify it one more time. Just add `R=301` for 301 redirect.  by default it makes 302 redirect. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @VaibhavJain okay, glad to help if it worked for you may mark it as accepted solution so It could help others as well.